# How can I get my Perl program to access GD?

Tags: perl, graphics, gd

I am using Linux Fedora 12.

I am learning Perl, and can run the simple "Hello world" programs, so Perl is install ok, but now I want to use GD in a Perl program, which starts:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use GD;
```

.. but it fails with:

```
[Harry@SN... ~]$ perl /home/Harry/perlprogs/trygraphic.pl
Can't locate GD.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ...
```

Please, what do I need to do? And, also very important: how do I find out what I need to know, to do it?

I believe I have installed GD, when I try the first line here:

```
[root@SN ... Harry]# perl -MCPAN -e install GD::Graph
[root@SN ... Harry]#
```

I get the second line with no other output between.

Comment: GD isn't GD::Graph, but installing GD::Graph should have installed GD. What do you get from `perl -MGD -E'say $INC{"GD.pm"}'`. Try as Harry and as root

Comment: try this : perl -MGD -e "print qq(hello world\n);"
any errors ?

Comment: You should first think about how to organize your libraries... I'm sure Fedora also has a perl-gd package ready, if you want to go this way.

Comment: Do you know that you're using a version of Fedora that hasn't been supported for over two years? Is there any reason why you aren't using an up to date versionb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the tantalizing answers. Taking the hint from  @Boris Dappen, (can't find know how to do the umlaut, sorry) I tried `yum install gd`which gave me:

> Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
>
> Setting up Install Process
>
> No package perl-gd available.
>    * Maybe you meant: perl-GD

So I used 
    `yum install perl-GD`. and then `use GD`in the proram worked ok.

Comment: That leaves me with the questions, "Have I installed a lot of stuff I don't need? How do I find out" Should I enter those in a separate question, or is it ok to edit the original, above?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want GD or GD::Graph? They are both available as pre-build packages for Fedora.

```
$ yum install perl-GD
$ yum install perl-GD-Graph
```